# Why does the SecureRandom#hex method double its length parameter n?

Tags: ruby

I came across the SecureRandom#hex method when trying to generate salts for passwords in a ruby on rails application. Why does it double the length parameter / insist that the returned string is even in length?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The method generates a random sequence of *n* bytes (cf. the `random_bytes` method), and then returns the base-16 representation of that sequence (which has two hex digits per byte).

This is also why the `base64` and `urlsafe_base64` methods return a string of length roughly 4*n*/3: they generate *n* bytes, and then perform the Base-64 encoding.